# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: xampp, phpmyadmin

I know this problem has come up before, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I someone could show me a step by step instruction what to do I would highly appreciate it.

Using XAMPP on Windows 10 64-bit.
Get this error message when using phpmyadmin.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

config.inc.php

```
/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';    

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';   

/*
 * End of servers configuration    
 */

?>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736319/phpmyadmin-error-mysqli-real-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-p)

Comment: I already have a pma user and password set in config.inc.php

Comment: *I already have a pma user and password set in config.inc.php* I see the password field in config is empty... and *using password: NO* means that the password is not transferred to MySQL during authentication.

Comment: The password is set to be empty.

Comment: Also get this error message Table phpmyadmin.pma__tracking doesn't exists in engine.

Answer (score 1):

Create the user "pma" in MySQL or change these lines in `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` for user and password for MySQL.

```
/* User for advanced features */  

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'your_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

All these still couldn't solve my problem. What I did to solve the problem was that I cleared the `controluser!` instead of maintaining the user `name'= 'pma'` clear it to look like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'] [$i]['controluser'] = ' ';
```

Where the user name becomes empty.
This should solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to figure out how to add privilege to the "pma" user on all my databases and tables, so I just changed it to use `root` instead

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
```